# How to change a drive letter that has Program Files

Tags: windows, disk-cloning, drive-letter

I have a small SSD C:\ drive and therefore have installed most of my programs on a second drive D:.  I now want to replace that platter drive with an M.2 SSD for improved performance.  I have cloned the drive onto the M.2, but am unsure of how to make the new M.2 my D:\ drive.

I am familiar with the Disk Management utility and can change drive letters, but since this one is part of my system, it is a more complicated matter.  My first thought is to use an external boot disk and then use the drive utility as I normally would to change drive letters, making the current D:\ drive something else, then make the M.2 the D:\ drive.  Is this a viable solution?

Comment: You should not and don't have to change the drive letter of a system drive.  You simply boot to the clone of the drive.  Once you do this your existing system drive will be a different drive letter allowing you to format it if you want.  You are guaranteed to break your system drive if you attempt to do your plan of changing the drive letter of the system volume.

Comment: @Ramhound - it's not precisely the system disk, but as I stated, is a secondary drive on which I have installed many programs.  It is NOT the boot disk, but IS a disk that has many items that are loaded when I boot as it has Program Files folders.  I have edited the title for clarity.

Comment: It's either a system disk or it isn't, a volume with a drive letter, cannot be "not precisely" a system disk.  If you cloned the drive, you should be able to change the drive letter of the smaller driver, and then change the drive of the larger drive within Disk Management.  This assumes both disks are connected and online.  Your desire to use a third-party partitioning tool is unwarranted.

Comment: @Ramshound - "should be able to" and "can" are not always compatible concepts.  It will not readily allow the change because some programs are loaded from that disk on restart.  It will allow me to change the D:\ drive to something else, but will not allow another drive to be assigned to D:\ without a reboot, which I believe will fail because there will no longer be a D:\ drive it will be looking for to load startup programs.  I have no desire to use a third-party tool, nor did I intend to imply that I did.

Comment: If you have programs, running in exestuation, and the executable exists on this other disk you can simply close the program.  There is nothing on that disk, that is required by Windows, unless you have moved your profile to that disk (which you didn't mention doing).  You can configured Windows into a minimal boot configuration allowing you change the drive letters of these disks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it setup is perfect! This is something I've done plenty of times and is really easy. Since both the original disk and new disk are clones and neither is needed to boot, all you have to do is swap drive letters.

1. Keep the boot and original platter disk connected.
2. Add the cloned disk and power up the machine.
3. When the system is up, open the Disk Management tool, choose the original disk and select *Change Drive Letter* but instead of changing the latter, click on the *Remove* button.
4. Choose the new disk and select *Change Drive Letter* again but this time use the  *Add* button to assign the same letter as the original disk (D:).
5. Close everything and restart the system.